# Clone tableau workbook into other project

Tags: tableau-api

In our current setup, we have a separate project for each customer. The customers all have the same dashboards but different data sources. Whenever we change a dashboard of one customer, we have to replicate the changes to all the other customers. Currently, this is a manual process, where we re-upload the changed workbook for each customer and replace the connected data sources. 
I now want to automate that process by using [tableaus rest API](https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python) in combination with their [document api](https://github.com/tableau/document-api-python). For the data sources, we are not using hyper files instead of having a live connection to a database.

This is my current implementation:

```
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('admin', 'tableau-admin')
server = TSC.Server('http://localhost:8080')

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):

  # download original workbook
  server.workbooks.download(workbook_id=source_work_book_id, filepath="tmp", include_extract=False)

  source_wb = Workbook('tmp/source.twbx')

  # get datasources which have connections
  wb_datasources = [s for s in source_wb.datasources if len(s.connections) != 0]

  # mappings to map datasource from source to target datasources
  # (all the datasources have the same name but are in different projects)
  dbname_to_datasource = {d.content_url: d.name for d in datasources if d.project_id == source_project_id}

  source_to_target = {d.name: d.content_url for d in datasources if d.project_id == target_project_id}

  # overwrite source datasources
  for datasource in wb_datasources:
    datasource.connections[0].dbname = source_to_target[dbname_to_datasource[datasource.connections[0].dbname]]

  source_wb.save_as("tmp/target.twbx")

  # write back to tableau server 
  new_workbook = TSC.WorkbookItem(target_project_id)

  server.workbooks.publish(new_workbook, file_path="tmp/target.twb", mode=TSC.Server.PublishMode.CreateNew)
```

I get the following error when uploading it:

```
400011: Bad Request
        There was a problem publishing the file 'target.twbx'.
```

It doesn't even work if I re-upload the workbook unmodified. If I change the download to include the extract file I can upload the unmodified workbook successfully:

```
server.workbooks.download(workbook_id=source_work_book_id, filepath=tmp_dir, include_extract=True)
```

The only problem with that is that I'm now adding unnecessary data and it also doesn't solve my issue of how to replace the data sources.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong or is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: I have done something similar (data source change in workbooks) using java and tabcmd instead of the rest API, but that was for .twb file and extracts were not involved. I couldn't follow the part where you save as "tmp/target.twbx" and publish as "tmp/target.twb". If you are using live connections to database why do you have extract and .twbx ?